# How to call OleCreatePropertyFrameIndirect from c#

Tags: c#, winapi, c++-cli, directx, directshow

I'm writing an application in c# that needs to display a property page. I have the code:

```
ISpecifyPropertyPages pProp = sourceObject as ISpecifyPropertyPages;
int hr = 0;

//Get the name of the filter from the FilterInfo struct
FilterInfo filterInfo;
hr = ((IBaseFilter) sourceObject).QueryFilterInfo(out filterInfo);
//DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
if (hr == 0)
{
// Get the propertypages from the property bag
CAUUID caGUID;
hr = pProp.GetPages(out caGUID);

if (hr == 0)
{
    // Create and display the OlePropertyFrame
    hr = Win32.OleCreatePropertyFrame(parentWindowForPropertyPage, 0, 0,
                      filterInfo.achName, 1,ref sourceObject,
                      caGUID.cElems,
                      caGUID.pElems, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
}
// Release COM objects
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pProp);
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(caGUID.pElems);
}
```

... which works fine IF the source isn't running - if the source is running the property window flashes up and immediately exits. I'm guessing I need to use OleCreatePropertyFrameIndirect instead and call it with the existing object but I can't find any examples of doing that via c# - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to be a problem with `OleCreatePropertyFrameIndirect`. Far more likely, the property page itself (and/or the source filter) has a problem and closes, throws an exception, generates access violation etc.

Comment: Yeah maybe although hr returns zero so not sure where to go from there

Comment: It returns zero because the error is internally caught by the property sheet. And it might be not even an error in first place - think of a property page calling [for whatever weird reason] `EndDialog` on its hosting sheet.

Comment: Some other software I've seen can access the property page whilst it's running so it is possible to do it. Calling the indirect method was about the only thing I could think of.